# Print in Brother RJ-3xxx using Raster Command Reference

Tags: printing, bitmap, raster, lzw

I'm trying to print a picture (Bitmap) in a label printer.
For this, I'm reading the Raster Command reference [cv_rj3000_eng_raster_100.pdf](http://download.brother.com/welcome/docp100056/cv_rj3000_eng_raster_100.pdf).
(pages 33-37)

Each raster line is One pixel length, each line contains [PackBits(TIFF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackBits). of algorithm data.

[image: Some raster commands]

The "0x67 0x00 0x02 0xe1 0x01" is an unit of raster data. In Green, where is "01" means 256 units + "d7" 215 (previous byte) then 471 units of raster data or 2.4inches length of label. (203dpi)

Why do I need to do this? Because the device from I want to print do not contain drivers. I connect wireless using Bluetooth.

The device is running a Windows compact embedded 7. Yes, I'm using c#.

What I like to do is create a bitmap, draw lines, put text and one or two images, read the bitmap data and transform in raster commands and then print.

The image above is from the file generated from Print to FILE instead to print to Printer(RJ-3150). (Printer Properties / Port tab)

I am very grateful for some help,

Antonio